# python web scraping Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: python, web-scraping

I wish to download a buildings database from BREEAM(Building Research Establishment Environmental Assessment Methodology). It has 65 pages so I would like to write a code to download more efficiently.

I had the following code

## import library

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

## Request to website and download HTML contents

url='https://tools.breeam.com/projects/explore/buildings.jsp?sectionid=0&projectType=Offices&rating=&countryID=56&client=&description=&certBody=&certNo=&developer=&location=London&buildingName=&assessor=&subschemeid=0&Submit=Search'
req=requests.get(url)
content=req.text

But I kept receiving error message:
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='tools.breeam.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /projects/explore/buildings.jsp?sectionid=0&projectType=Offices&rating=&countryID=56&client=&description=&certBody=&certNo=&developer=&location=London&buildingName=&assessor=&subschemeid=0&Submit=Search (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000020523F02048>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For me this already works:

```
import requests

url = "https://tools.breeam.com/projects/explore/buildings.jsp?sectionid=0&projectType=Offices&rating=&countryID=56&client=&description=&certBody=&certNo=&developer=&location=London&buildingName=&assessor=&subschemeid=0&Submit=Search"

response = requests.get(url)

print(response)
```

No headers and cookies needed. Have you already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39064126/failed-to-establish-a-new-connection) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013220/max-retries-exceeded-with-url-in-requests)? And please format your question the right way next time :)